# AVX2 integer comparison for smaller equal

Tags: c, integer, compare, avx, avx2

What is the most efficient way to compare two 4x 64bit-Integer AVX vectors for `<=`.

From the Intel Intrinsics Guide we have

- `_mm256_cmpgt_epi64(__m256i a, __m256i b)` = a >  b
- `_mm256_cmpeq_epi64(__m256i a, __m256i b)` = a == b

for comparisons

and

- `_mm256_and_si256(__m256i a, __m256i b)` = a & b
- `_mm256_andnot_si256(__m256i a, __m256i b)` = ~a & b
- `_mm256_or_si256(__m256i a, __m256i b)` = a | b
- `_mm256_xor_si256(__m256i a, __m256i b)` = a ^ b

for logical operations.

My approach was:

`// check = ( a <= b ) = ~(a > b) & 0xF..F`
`__m256i a     = ...`
`__m256i b     = ...`
`__m256i tmp   = _mm256_cmpgt_epi64(a, b)`
`__m256i check = _mm256_andnot_si256(tmp, _mm256_set1_epi64x(-1))`

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a smarter (more efficient) way of doing it, as the unnecessary `0xF..F` is bothering me

Comment: Have you checked what a good compiler will do for this? gcc generates the all-ones mask for the "and not" by comparing a temporary register for equality with itself (always compares true), so you don't need to keep this around as a constant, and according to Agner Fog's analysis, the instruction is recognized as independent of the previous value of the register, so you can quickly generate the mask and don't need to keep it around, wasting a register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that there's no direct way to get the mask you really want, only an inverted mask: `A gt B` = `A nle B`.

There's no vector-NOT instruction, so you do need a vector of all-ones as well as an extra instruction to invert a vector.  (Or a vector of all-zero and `_mm256_cmpeq_epi8`, but that can't run on as many execution ports as `_mm256_xor_si256` with an all-ones vector.)    See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for performance info, esp. Agner Fog's guide.

The other bitwise boolean option, `_mm256_andn_si256` is just as good as xor.  It isn't commutative, and slightly more complicated to mentally verify that you got it right.  xor-with-all-ones is a good idiom for flip-all-the-bits.

---

**Instead of spending an instruction inverting the mask, in most code it's possible to just use it the opposite way.**

e.g. if it's an input to a `blendv`, then reverse the order of the operands to the blend.  Instead of
`_mm256_blendv_epi8(a, b, A_le_B_mask)`, use
`_mm256_blendv_epi8(b, a, A_nle_B_mask)`

If you were going to `_mm_and` something with the mask, use `_mm_andn` instead.

If you were going to `_mm_movemask` and test for all-zero, you can instead test for all-ones.  It will compile to a `cmp eax, -1` instruction instead of a `test eax,eax`, which is just as efficient.  If you were going to bitscan for the first 1, you will have to invert it.  An integer `not` instruction (from using `~` on the movemask result) is cheaper than doing it on the vector.

---

You only have a problem if you were going to OR or XOR, because those instruction don't come in flavours that negate one of their inputs.  (IDK if Intel just didn't want to add a `PORN` mnemonic, but probably `PAND` and `PANDN` get more use, esp. before variable-blend instructions.

Comment: @PaulR: Apparently my sleepy brain knew the right answer involved some kind of reversing of operands, but ran out of steam before noticing that I had it totally wrong.  >.<

Comment: you're right about the `blendv` intrinsics, but I actually would need an OR after that and there is no NOR for it - but thanks anyway

Comment: @user2399267......seemsgood:  `NOR` would be `~(a|b)`.  The operation you'd need, `(~a | b)` would be called `ORN`, like `ANDN`.  IIRC, AVX512 vector integer comparisons take a predicate argument (encoded in an immediate byte), so AVX512 will finally give us a wide choice of comparison operators, the way `cmpps` currently does.

Comment: @PeterCordes: well I think it's the first time I've ever spotted a mistake in one of your posts, so your batting average is way better than mine. ;-) I'll delete my comment to reduce the noise, now that you've updated the answer...